# possible for PHP to read/parse the current vhosts' Apache VirtualHost config block, to retrieve ErrorLog and CustomLog settings?

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, error-log

Is it possible for PHP to read/parse the current vhosts' Apache VirtualHost config block, in particular, to retrieve ErrorLog and CustomLog settings?

To be clear we do not need the PHP error log path, that is easy to retrieve.

I couldn't find any way in `phpinfo` or `_SERVER/getenv()` or PHP Apache functions (`apache_module()`, `apache_note()`, `apache_getenv()`)

The codebase is used for multiple virtual hosts on multiple servers so we can't hard code the Apache access and error log paths in PHP (or in `.htaccess` `SetEnv` or some ini/csv/whatever file etc), as it may not always match up with what has been set in `<VirtualHost>` - someone in Operations may update the VirtualHost but a developer may not update the code or whatever the code is using to find the same path. We cannot have a  SetEnv under or above the line of CustomLog with the same value, as it's still possible one will be updated without the other (human error etc.).

My best hope was `apache_getenv()` but I've tried `apache_getenv('CustomLog')` and it does not return anything.

Would be ok to run a series of `system()/exec()` calls to run cli functions to find them, but not ideal.

The `ServerName` may not match the current vhost being called, as `ServerAlias` may have a different virtualhost that contains regex, so once the path to Apache conf has been found, manually grepping through the file is not ideal/reliable.

Apache 2.2.16 (Unix)
PHP 5.3.3
CentOS release 5.5 (Final)

Please tell me I've missed something obvious ;)

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need the path of the ErrorLog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please tell me I've missed something
>   obvious ;)

No, you haven't. Apache simply does not store this string anyplace where you can get at it. From, [mod_log_config.c](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/tags/2.2.19/modules/loggers/mod_log_config.c) (note the `fmt` argument which is stored in a `config_log_state` struct):

```
static const char *add_custom_log(cmd_parms *cmd, void *dummy, const char *fn,
                                  const char *fmt, const char *envclause)
{
    const char *err_string = NULL;
    multi_log_state *mls = ap_get_module_config(cmd->server->module_config,
                                                &log_config_module);
    config_log_state *cls;

    cls = (config_log_state *) apr_array_push(mls->config_logs);
    cls->condition_var = NULL;
    if (envclause != NULL) {
        if (strncasecmp(envclause, "env=", 4) != 0) {
            return "error in condition clause";
        }
        if ((envclause[4] == '\0')
            || ((envclause[4] == '!') && (envclause[5] == '\0'))) {
            return "missing environment variable name";
        }
        cls->condition_var = apr_pstrdup(cmd->pool, &envclause[4]);
    }

    cls->fname = fn;
    cls->format_string = fmt;
    if (fmt == NULL) {
        cls->format = NULL;
    }
    else {
        cls->format = parse_log_string(cmd->pool, fmt, &err_string);
    }
    cls->log_writer = NULL;

    return err_string;
}
```

You must either (regardless if you've previously stated that you cannot):

- Convince the developers to keep SetEnv and CustomLog identical
- Parse the conf files yourself and keep your fingers crossed
- <strike>Modify `mod_log_config.c` (bad idea!)</strike>
- Forget the whole thing! ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda hackish, but you could put

```
ErrorLog /path/to/logfile
SetEnv ErrorLog /path/to/logfile
```

in your httpd.conf, so you could use the apache_getenv() function. getenv() doesn't retrieve configuration directives, just actual environment variables. So.. put the log path into an environment variable.

Comment: From OP: "We cannot have a SetEnv under or above the line of CustomLog with the same value, as it's still possible one will be updated without the other"

Comment: That's one way to look at it :)